# How to access functions that are inside a module.exports declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been given an `app.js` file that was created by `Webpack`. Having looked at the file (which is rather big) it starts with:

```
module.exports =
 (() => { // webpackBootstrap
"use strict";

// Some webpack stuff here

// Then come the functions
function ssrRender(_ctx, _push, _parent, _attrs, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
 // Function stuff
});

function SiteHeader_type_template_id_a899d1f6_ssrRender(_ctx, _push, _parent, _attrs, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
// Function stuff
});

function makeApp(args) {
// Function stuff
});

})(); //End
```

I have read this file into a variable by running which works fine:

```
const serverApp = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/app.js'), 'utf-8')
```

However I really need to use a `function` in this file like `makeApp()`. But if I do this it says `makeApp` is not a function:

```
console.log(serverApp.makeApp());
```

So how do you use the functions in this file?

Update: I have seen an example of someone doing this which makes no sense to me and doesnt work anyway:

`const makeApp = require(serverApp).default`

Comment: The will have to be returned from the function.

Comment: you can't they are hidden in that iife you have to return an object with them.

Comment: a) you need to `require` the file, unless you plan to do something weird with the source code string b) the module IEFE probably has a `return` statement which you haven't shown us

Answer (score 0):

1 - This auto invoke function is really necessary?
2 - Shouldn't these functions be some properties of an object, instead of creating them and  returning nothing in the end?

If this auto invoke function is really necessary, you should at least return an object, passing as properties these functions.